# Filtering a join table by values less than or equal to their own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking to publish all records that have an attendance of less than or equal to (<=) the current record, but I'm struggling.

My model is...

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :attendances
    has_many :classes, :through => :attendances 

end

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :student
    validates :student_id, presence: true
    belongs_to :class
    validates :class_id, presence: true

end

class Class < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :attendances
    has_many :students, :through => :attendances    

end
```

I want to show against the current student all other students with an attendance of <= to them, but my calculation is wrong.

So this is on the 'Student' page, and it shows a table of other students in their classes whose attendance is less than or equal to their own.

Someone alerted me to;

```
<% student_attend = @student.attendance.sum(:attend) %>

<% @student.joins(:attendance).where("attendance.attend <= ?", student_attend).each do |student| %>
```

...but this doesn't quite do as I hoped.

Would someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance! Happy to PayPal some coffee money if someone can help :-)

Comment: can you please post the structure of Attendance model ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippent at your controller level or at your model level. Its better if you use this at the controller level.

Your current student object is `@student`

```
@ids=[]
Student.find(:all).each do |stu|
   @ids.push stu.id if stu.attendances.count<=@student.attendances.count
end
```